# Set an object using >> operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have overloaded >> operator for many classes , but there is a difference in this case . I can't generally set class members in operator's function . i need to use the char*-argument constructor to set the object but when i do it , the program stops working . You can see the function below :

```
istream & operator >>(istream &stream ,Big& b)
{
    char *str;
    stream>>str;
    b=Big(str);
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say your program "stops working"?

Comment: And what are those runtime errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *str;
stream>>str;
```

invokes undefined behavior because you haven't allocated memory for `str`. Either allocate memory, or use a `std::string` instead (preferred).

Comment: Oh what a ridiculous mistake i made ! It worked . Thank you .

Comment: sorry for being picky, but that should be **an** `std::string`, right?

Comment: I always pronounced it [es tee dee string]. May I ask how you pronounce it?

Comment: No , i just allocated the memory using "char *str=new char[9];"

Comment: @armanradan if you know the size beforehand, just use `char str[9]` instead.

Comment: I pronounce it [es tee dee string] too .

Comment: @Luchian Grigore : No , it was just an example . i want to use a class member to size the char* .

Comment: @Default I'm with you.  I always use **an** before `std::` too.

Comment: I have always read it as `standard string`, which makes the **a** a better fit. Guess Luchian might be doing that to.

Comment: @BoPersson when I read it in my mind, I do pronounce it "an". But when I write it, I write it with "a"...

Answer (score 2):

You try to read input into an uninitialized pointer. Use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`char *str` can't hold the result of streaming from `stream` (unless you're reading a pointer, but I doubt that's your intention).  You probably want `std::string str`.